# C++ vector operations in C#

Tags: c#, c++, stack, stdvector

I am trying to rewrite from c++ into a c# program using vectors. I have a problem with the code given below. The problem is the line in the loop:
`tab[(s[i])].push_back(i)`. I'd like to know if it's possible to do something like this in c#. Thank you.

```
#define MAXN 1000005
int n, pos, temp;
vector<int> tab[255];
char s[MAXN];
int main(){
  temp = scanf("%d", &n);
  temp = scanf("%s", s);
  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        tab[int(s[i])].push_back(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: you can use List<int> and call list.Add(i)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach would be to use `List<int>()`.

In that case

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    myList.Add(i);
}
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reverse Function of the C# List.

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    myList.Add(i);
}
// using method Reverse() 
myList.Reverse();
```